# Load file from website as dart file and import into my flutter view

Tags: file, flutter, dart, import

I would like to create a quote list in my Flutter app, which I keep on a server and update every time I start the app. I have done this offline until now, so the file was static and no changes were possible. How is it possible that I load this file into the app and then import it into my Flutter view?

```
    class NewsListData {
  NewsListData({
    this.imagePath = '',
    this.titleTxt = '',
    this.subTxt = "",
    this.dist = 1.8,
    this.anmeldeschluss = '',
    this.rating = 4.5,
    this.kursgebuehr = 180,
    this.id1 = true,
    this.id2 = true,
    this.id3 = true,
  });

  String imagePath;
  String titleTxt;
  String subTxt;
  double dist;
  double rating;
  String anmeldeschluss;
  int kursgebuehr;
  bool id1;
  bool id2;
  bool id3;
  List id;

  void run() {
    List id = null;
    id = NewsList.where((item) => item.id3).toList();
    print(List);
  }

  static List<NewsListData> NewsList = <NewsListData>[
    NewsListData(
      imagePath: 'assets/kurse/cmas/cmas1.png',
      titleTxt: 'CMAS*',
      subTxt: 'Inkl. Lehrmaterial',
      anmeldeschluss: '01.März 2020',
      kursgebuehr: 95,
      id1: false,
      id2: false,
      id3: true,
    ),
    NewsListData(
      imagePath: 'assets/kurse/cmas/cmas2.png',
      titleTxt: 'CMAS**',
      subTxt: 'Inkl. Lehrmaterial',
      anmeldeschluss: '01.März 2020',
      kursgebuehr: 115,
      id1: false,
      id2: false,
      id3: true,
    ),
    NewsListData(
      imagePath: 'assets/kurse/cmas/cmas3.png',
      titleTxt: 'CMAS***',
      subTxt: 'Inkl. Lehrmaterial',
      anmeldeschluss: '01.März 2020',
      kursgebuehr: 115,
      id1: false,
      id2: false,
      id3: true,
    ),
  ];
}
```

Comment: Convert it to a JSON file and retrieve it with an HTTP call.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Dart class (later referred to as `QuoteClass`) based on your expected HTTP response. To create them automatically, you can use this [website](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)
2. Create an HTTP service that can execute HTTP requests (use an HTTP package like [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for example)
3. In a controller, make (probably) a GET request to your server (via the HTTP service created in step 2. This will result in a JSON `String`.

Now you need to convert the `String` to your Dart Class. You could do something like:

```
String jsonResponse = await httpService.get('https://www.my-website.com/quotes');
Map<String, dynamic> exampleObject = json.decode(jsonResponse);
QuoteClass myQuotes = QuoteClass.fromJson(exampleObject);
```